# setAttribute and getAtttribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am setting String value this way:

```
<%
String str1="hi"+":"+"hello";
pageContext.setAttribute("str", str1,pageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
%>
```

I am retrieving String value on the same jsp page this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var getstr=<%=pageContext.getAttribute("str")%>
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

All code is in `<head> </head>` tags

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Nothing is syntactically incorrect. Which line do you get this error on?

Comment: The js variable should be quoted if it's a string. You still have to render legal JavaScript. Is the syntax error from JS or Java?

Comment: I get error at this line var getstr=<%=pageContext.getAttribute("str")%>

Comment: @DaveNewton error is in JS

Comment: The erroneous line you pointed out `var getstr=<%=pageContext.getAttribute("str")%>` does not issue any compiler error. True being  a JavaScript assignment statement, there should be a semicolon at the end of the line but that's a story apart. (I have double-checked it).

Answer (score 1):

As said by Dave Newton in comments "js variable should be quoted if it's a string"

```
var getstr='<%=pageContext.getAttribute("str")%>'
```

Many Thanks @Dave Newton

Comment: The story of quotation marks is different. What if you want to assign a numeric value to a JavaScript variable? After all, this is not the culprit of the compile-time error you got (JSP 2.3.3 does not issue any compiler error with the code snippets you posted).

Comment: @Tiny OP states it's a JS error, but even if he hadn't,  a semicolon is optional, so the only way there could be an error is if it needed quotes-fairly simple to deduce.

Comment: Yes, the error is not shown until run-time, in this case. Thank you @DaveNewton :)